# Behavior of php function arguments' datatypes

Tags: php

```
function addition(int $number1, int $number2): int
{
    return $number1 + $number2;
}

print('<pre>');
print_r(addition(2, "10"));
print('</pre>');
```

As a result of above code, it gives me 12. But it should give me an error. Because the second parameter should be an `int`. But I passed `string`. Can anyone tell me what kind of behavior happen here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that it gets typecast to an integer, as `"10" == 10`. The problem arise when you say `addition(2,'3x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare [**strict_types()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php). By default, it is `scalar type` which is not strict. Also `strict_types()` has more control over your codes.

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function addition(int $number1, int $number2): int
{
    return $number1 + $number2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using PHP7, add this:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
```

at the very first line of the script, and than you will get an error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PHP is loosely typed scripting language and there is no restriction on the variables type and their nature.

```
$i = "10";
```

will be considered both integer and the string.

you can read more about this nature by searching about "Why PHP is loosely typed?"

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by "considered both integer and the string"? As far as I see, that is definitely a string that might get casted, but it cannot be both at the same time